# Sum of $\frac{x^2}{2*1} - \frac{x^3}{3*2} + \frac{x^4}{4*3} - ...$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have to find the sum of :

$$\frac{x^2}{2*1} - \frac{x^3}{3*2} + \frac{x^4}{4*3} - \frac{x^5}{5*4} +\cdots$$

So far I have :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n)}$$

which is very close to $\ln(1+x)$... but I just can't figure out what I have to do from there.

Comment: Hint: Since it's close to the series for $\ln(1+x)$, write out some terms and compare the two series. Do you see how to get from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

On its domain of convergence, the derivative of the sum of this power series is
$$x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\dotsm=\ln(1+x).$$

Comment: Thanks, with that I get that my function is (x+1)ln(x+1) +ln(x+1)-x-1+C? Just wondering what to do with C? Do I just leave it in?

Comment: No. The power series is equal to $0$ if $x=0$, so you can deduce a value for $C$.

Comment: The exact solution is $\; (x+1)\ln(x+1)-x$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\frac {\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n(n-1)}=\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n-1}}{n-1}=(-1)^nx^{n-2}=(-x)^{n-2}$$
so that we expect $f(x)_=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n(n-1)}$ to be a function with $f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^{n} =\frac1{1+x}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n)} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) \, (-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n+1} \\
&= x \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&= x \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n}}{n} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n}}{n} \\
&= (x+1) \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \, x^{n}}{n} - x \\
&= (x+1) \, \ln(1+x) - x.
\end{align}